# Convert mysql query to laravel's DB facade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to convert this mySQL query to the laravel DB() facade:

```
SELECT
   t.*,
   t_users.username as topic_user,
   last_reply.user_id as last_reply_user_id,
   r_users.username as last_reply_username,
   last_reply.replies_count,
   IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) as last_update

FROM
   topics as t
   left join users as t_users on t_users.id = t.user_id
   left join ( select r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies order by created_at desc) as r group by r.topic_id ) as last_reply on last_reply.topic_id = t.id
   left join users as r_users on r_users.id = last_reply.user_id

ORDER BY IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) DESC
```

I tried many different approaches for almost 2 days now, but just can't get it to work. The latest one was:

```
        $query = DB::table('topics as t')
            ->leftJoin('users as t_users', 't_users.id', '=', 't.user_id')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('select r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies order by created_at desc) as r group by r.topic_id'), 'last_reply.topic_id', '=', 't.id')
            ->leftJoin('users as r_users', 'r_users.id', '=', 'last_reply.user_id')
            ->select(
               't.*,
               t_users.username as topic_user,
               last_reply.user_id as last_reply_user_id,
               r_users.username as last_reply_username,
               last_reply.replies_count,
               IFNULL(last_reply.created_at,t.created_at) as last_update'
            );
```

And causes this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select
>   r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies order by
>   cre' at line 1 (SQL: select `t`.`*,` as `` from `topics` as `t` left
>   join `users` as `t_users` on `t_users`.`id` = `t`.`user_id` left join
>   select r.*,count(r.id) as replies_count from (select * from replies
>   order by created_at desc) as r group by r.topic_id on
>   `last_reply`.`topic_id` = `t`.`id` left join `users` as `r_users` on
>   `r_users`.`id` = `last_reply`.`user_id`)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: so what problem you are facing now?

Comment: That I am unable to convert it to laravel :/ I am just getting all sorts of different errors.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? You can just use `DB::statement` or `DB::select` and keep most of the query the same

Comment: Post the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Updated my question @maiorano84

Comment: @andrewtweber I tried that but got all sorts of errors. If you're able to do that, I would appreciate that.